# HOW TO RESOLVE: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

This error occurs in Firefox console when loading 3rd party Javascript. But Firefox console gives absolutely no information as to whereabouts in the JS this issue occurs. The 3rd Party JS has a host of different JSON parts to it.

I am not familiar enough with JS to dig in and mess around with the code toooo much or spend hours fragmenting it and taking it apart and putting it back together again.

## NOTE

There are a lot of questions with identical titles, and each of these show very specific issues with very specific responses. My question is not really about wanting to find the issue in this case (although that would be great).

## My Question

How should I (any anyone else) approach trying to find where this error is;

- How do we find what data is causing this error?
- How do we find which line of JS causes this error?

Reading the MDN (etc) on JSON errors It seems to be easy to resolve once it's been found, but the case is I am having troubles finding how to go abouts digging out where in the JS this issue occurs and/or which data is causing the JSON error.

## UPDATE

Further to comments, here is the Debug flow output from Firefox; I'm a little lost in here but this still doesn't seemt to show me what is actually going on.

[image]

Comment: If this is occurring in third-party JS, then the problem is there, not in your own code that you can fix.

Comment: You should be able to use the stack trace in the debugger to see which call to `JSON.parse()` is getting the error.

Comment: What does the JSON returned from the API look like?

Comment: @Barmar it is 3rd party JS but it's on my local server, downloaded from their github (Stripe Payment Gateway)

Comment: @evolutionxbox where would I find the JSON return?

Comment: I understand that. But it still means that the author of the code you downloaded should fix it, not you. Unless you think you're competent to contribute to the project.

Comment: In the debugger. You should be able to see the variable that's used in the call to `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @Martin you could find it in the browser tools, under the network tab?

Comment: @Barmar I would love to agree with you, but my issue is not so much about the issue itself but about how Firefox console doesn't seem to give me any pointers to identify the error itself. There are about 5 JSON things happening in the JS and I have no idea which one is failing, or exactly what data is causing it to fail, that's what I'd like to establish `:-)`

Comment: If you have the console open when the error happens, the script should stop. Then you can examine the stack trace in the debugger, and see where it's happening.

Comment: Make sure you're not using minified JavaScript, as the code will be unintelligible.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the Debug flow. To be honest I can't see a lot that's actually useful there; I suspect I'm looking in the wrong parts of it? Thanks.

Comment: @Barmar ahh, with the Debugger tab open, the error does now give back a JS file and line (event-loop.js + drop down details) that the issue occured on. It is a Stripe hosted file. I think this should be enough to feed back to them for help. Thanks for the guidance here.

Comment: Look at the network request, look what is there

Comment: @epascarello there are a lot of network requests and all return HTTP 200 and superficially look absolutely fine so it is hard to easily distinguish an imporper request

Comment: @epascarello If you could add some more help; what would someone be looking for on Network Requests to find a piece JSON.parse error data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some clear pointers that came up in the comments below the question:

- Use the **Debugger** Firefox Inspector tab before refreshing the page and reloading the error.
- Somewhat unexpectedly, when on the Debugger tab, the same console error (at the bottom of my screenshot) this time shows a file reference and line number reference and can be clicked on to show a cascade of details.
- As mentioned by [evolutionxbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989920/evolutionxbox) and [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) the Debugger tab should also be showing the variable that's used in the call to `JSON.parse`.
- Using the Debugger **Breakpoints** tickboxes was very useful for establishing what part of what code was running when the error was encountered.

*More will be added here*